# Create vector and get all images ?

Tags: php, preg-match

I need some help, geting all the images in my article.
At the moment to get only the first image i use this :

```
$first_img = '';
$mycontent = $row['post_content'];
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $my1content, $matches); 
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];
if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
$first_img = "/img/default.png";}
```

This get only the first image from the article..

So what i need it , to get all the images from the article, and show them in a row.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `preg_match_all` function will return an array matches, `foreach` loop would be sufficient.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

```
foreach($matches as $val) {
    echo $val;
}
```

Better pattern: `/<img(?:(?!src).)+src="?([^"\']+)/i`

To handle the multiple matches you can do the following:

```
$mycontent = '<img something="null" src="ggggg.gif"><br/><img src="bob.jpg">';
$output = preg_match_all('/<img(?:(?!src).)+src="?([^"\']+)/i', $mycontent, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER); // find all src attributes
foreach($matches as $val) { //loop over <img> tags matches
    echo $val[1];
}
```

Comment: Please can you paste the code here how it should be ? thank you

Comment: Updated the answer, improved pattern.